# MAPI Stub Library cannot initialize MAPI for Outlook 2016(64bit)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, outlook, mapi

My computer is Windows 7(64bit), I then install Outlook 2016(64bit).

Then I follow the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/how-to-link-to-mapi-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN to use MAPIStubLibrary.

The version of MAPIStubLibrary I use is updated on 2018-02-26.

I include the MapiStubLibrary.cpp and StubUtils.cpp to my project directly. Then I call the following line to initialize MAPI:

```
if (MAPIInitialize(NULL) != S_OK)
  AfxMessageBox(_T("Initialize MAPI fails!"));
```

However, when invoke the above code, I will see a message box said "

```
Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request. Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client.
```

And the function MAPIInitialize(NULL) will return E_FAIL. But I have set Outlook 2016(64bit) as the default mail client.

I think maybe I need to update MAPIStubLibrary to its latest version, so I go to https://github.com/stephenegriffin/MAPIStubLibrary and then download the latest version.

Then copy all files under library folder to my project, including MapiStubLibrary.cpp, StubUtils.cpp and StubUtils.h.

Then I rebuild the project in VS2008. However, this time I get a lot of errors:

```
.\MAPIStubLibrary\MapiStubLibrary.cpp(1155) : error C2065: 'nullptr' : undeclared identifier
.\MAPIStubLibrary\StubUtils.cpp(44) : error C2039: 'function' : is not a member of 'std'
.\MAPIStubLibrary\StubUtils.cpp(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
.\MAPIStubLibrary\StubUtils.cpp(44) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
.\MAPIStubLibrary\StubUtils.cpp(45) : error C2086: 'int mapistub::function' : redefinition
        .\MAPIStubLibrary\StubUtils.cpp(44) : see declaration of 'mapistub::function'
.\MAPIStubLibrary\StubUtils.cpp(49) : error C2065: 'logLoadMapiCallback' : undeclared identifier
```

Why?

**Update:**

I double check and confirm the Outlook is 64bit:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means Outlook is either not installed or that it has a different bitness. Check Outlook bitness in File | Office Outlook | About Outlook.

Comment: The Outlook is 64bit. And the application is also 64bit. I have updated with the screenshot.

Comment: Try to run MFCMAPI from https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/releases and see if it runs into the same problem.